# Reactjs - alignment of textbox within Table row

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a table row that I've been trying to get aligned properly but can't seem to figure it out.

Each table row has a small arrow to the left whose position will toggle depending on whether or not the row details are being shown.  Then there is a textbox followed by various other text elements that are placed using a Bootstrap grid along the row.

```
<tr className={this.props.showDetails === true ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'} onClick={...}>
    <Glyphicon glyph={this.props.showDetails === true ? 'triangle-bottom' : 'triangle-right'} />
    <td className='col-md-1'>
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControl type="text"></FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
    </td>

    <td className='col-md-7'>
        Placeholder text
    </td>

    <td className='col-md-2'>
        Placeholder text
    </td>

    <td className='col-md-1'>
        Placeholder text
    </td>

    <td className='col-md-1'>
        Placeholder text
    </td>
</tr>
```

So my problem is that the arrow is flush against textbox like so (and I want it to be more spaced out):

[image]

I tried adding a `margin-right` to the arrow but it didn't push the elements to the right at all.

So I tried doing nested `td`s like so...

```
<td className='col-md-2'>
    <td className='col-md-2'>
        <Glyphicon glyph={this.props.showDetails === true ? 'triangle-bottom' : 'triangle-right'} />
    </td>

    <td className='col-md-10'>
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControl type="text"></FormControl>
        </FormGroup>   
    </td>
</td>
```

...which actually kind of worked but there are some issues with this. First, I get warnings that a `td` can't be a child of a `td`. And in addition, because I'm trying to add some row details on a toggle, I can't the row details to align properly.

So then I tried putting the arrow in its own `td` which them makes it look really spread apart.

[image]

So I tried simply messing with margins which also kind of worked.  I added classes like this and some CSS.

```
<td className='col-md-1'>
    <FormGroup className='formGroupAlignment'>
        <FormControl type="text"></FormControl>
    </FormGroup>
</td>

<td className='col-md-7 leftAlignment'>
    Placeholder text
</td>
```

and CSS:

```
.formGroupAlignment {
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.leftAlignment {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

And now it looks more like what I want:

[image]

But although it looks okay, the behavior is slightly off now. If I slowly hover my mouse over the right-side of the text box, the mouse cursor doesn't turn into the text-select cursor (the one that looks like a capital I) until about 1/3 of the way from the right side. This is because the `margin-right` pushes the `Placeholder text` into the area of the textbox so even though visually everything looks okay, the text area is occluded slightly.

So after all that history, my question is: what can I do to get my stuff to align correctly and achieve the proper element behaviors?